# Sending E-Mails through Windows forms

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have an mail server installed for intranet mailing in my office. I have been using Windows live and outlook express for accessing emails on client machines. I am planning to build a reporting application in c# winforms in which certain reports has to be created and it should be sent through email for all the users. Reports should be generated and sent by any of the client systems. For mailing purpose I have done the following.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("192.168.0.113",25);

message.From = new MailAddress("abc@123.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("def@123.com"));
message.Subject = "Test";
message.Body = "Content";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@123.com", "123456");
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(message);
```

domain name has been changed.192.168.0.113 is smtp host.same seetings are given in outlook express and windows live.user credentials are correct but application is throwing the follwing SMTP exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException'
>   occurred in System.dll InnerException:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException HResult=-2147467259 Message=No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 192.168.0.113:25 Source=System ErrorCode=10061
>   NativeErrorCode=10061 StackTrace: at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) InnerException:

This is what I have got.. any idea about this? it says machine actively refused. what could be wrong?? please suggest..

Comment: can you ping the IP address? This error usually means either that your firewall is blocking you, or there is no application listening on that port.  Make sure no other applications are using the same port as you are trying to connect to

Comment: try using port 587..

Comment: i tried pinging it works fine. and also tried port 587 but of no use.

Comment: through outlook i am able to recieve and send mail so its not a problem with the server and firewall right..??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use smtp.gmail.com in

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("192.168.0.113",25);
```

like

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",25);
```

If your host is gmail.

Find your host here

https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html

Comment: did he mention anywhere that he uses "gmail"?

Comment: If sender mail provider is gmail then it's smtp.gmail.com. But this is not actual email i think "abc@123.com

Comment: i have mentioned differenrt host name here 123.com is not an  actuall domain. i have a local hmail server installed and it serves for only intranet on the lan. i am using windows live, outlook express and thunderbird in client machines to acess mails.

Answer (score 0):

Check your antivirus. I have faced this issue long time ago.